# Cannot restart apache onto Linux Mint

Tags: linux, virtualbox, apache-http-server, linux-mint

Linux Mint is the Guest System on Virtual Box

Windows 8.1 is the Host System

```
danko@danko-VirtualBox ~ $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

[sudo] password for danko: 

 Restarting web server apache2                           
 AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80

(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down

AH00015: Unable to open logs

Action 'start' failed.
```

The Apache error log may have more information.
                                                                 [fail]
  The apache2 instance did not start within 20 seconds. Please read the log files to discover problems

**The Apache error log is empty**

> danko@danko-VirtualBox ~ $ netstat -punta | grep LISTEN

(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*            LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*            LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*            LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*            LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*            LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::139                  :::*                 LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                 LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                 LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::445                  :::*                 LISTEN
```

Answer (score 0):

Apache can’t start because Port 80 is already being used by some other
process (as confirmed by the output of `netstat`). Run the following command
to see what that process is:

```
sudo lsof -i | grep "http (LISTEN)"
```

Once you have determined what that process is, you can (cleanly) stop it and then start Apache.

Answer (score 0):

It may be installed as a service and needs to be restarted as such:

$ sudo service apache2 restart